# Excel VBA fill out web form and retrieve results

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am new to web scraping so I was trying to start with something simple after watching a few tutorials.  The code below is supposed to open a browser, go to Google, and search for "test".  I keep getting an error on the last step.

```
Sub test1()

 Dim ie As Object
 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 ie.Visible = True
 ie.navigate "http://google.com/"
 Do While ie.Busy
  Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now");p-p;l.k,./../..p
 Loop

 ie.document.getElementsByName("input").Value = "test"

End Sub
```

Google comes up in Explorer but I get this error on the last line:

Run-time error '438':  Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: getElementsByName returns a collection not a single node. .Value is a property of a single node. 1) You need to index into that collection 2) Assuming input is the right target type element you then need to use the appropriate index for the collection.

Comment: @QHarr Thank you.  How do I figure out which is the right index for the search box?

Comment: Use the browser elements tab and press ctrl + F and enter input in the box and hit enter and cycle through the matches. Also, right click the element and copy selector and see what css selector pattern is returned. You can use css selectors with ie.document.querySelector("<css pattern goes here")